# How do I know if filepond is rendered?

Tags: vue.js, filepond

I need to manipulate some DOM properties manually (change the style of a file element dynamically). I search for the desired element by `document.getElementById ("filepond - item-" + id)`.

But I run into a problem if the Filepond DOM elements with initial files have not been rendered yet (`getElementById()` does not find any element).

I am currently solving this problem with `this.$NextTick()`:

```
<template>
 <file-pond
    ref="filepond"
    :server="server"
    :files="files"
    @initfile.once="markMainImage"
  />
</template>
<script>
[...]
  methods: {
    async markMainImage () {
      await this. $ nextTick ();
      document.getElementById ("filepond - item-" + id).classList.add ("main-image");
    },
  },
</script>
```

But this is not convenient and not very reliable.
Can the `FilePond:loaded` event be used for this purpose (https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/instance/events/#filepond-loaded-event)?

If so, how do you use it in Vue?

`@loaded="markMainImage"` doesn't fire

Or is there another way to find out if filepond is rendered with initial files?

Comment: You could use the `addfile` event or use a `MutationObserver` to detect changes to the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Rik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774081/rik) for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519655/how-do-i-know-if-filepond-is-rendered?noredirect=1#comment124698793_70519655)

```
@addfile.once="markMainImage"
```

It works.